# Why is 'case' inside a switch statement negative indented?

Tags: xcode, swift, swift2

I don't think this is entirely a Swift / Xcode thing, as I've seen it in other languages / IDEs as well.

Why is 'case' inside  a switch statement negative indented *(I'm not sure if that's the correct way of wording that)*?

I would expect a Switch statement to look something like this

```
switch(type) {
    case 1:
        // do something
    break;
    case 2:
        // do something else
    break;
    default:
        // default
    break;
}
```

But Xcode insists on this

```
switch(type) {
case 1:
    // do something
    break;
case 2:
    // do something else
    break;
default:
    // default
    break;
}
```

Is this a bug, or is there a reason for this? If so, what is it? It's something that has bugged me for quite some time.

Comment: Thanks @BSMP, I didn't see that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, I would guess that the `break` statement belongs to the "section" in the case clause. And as any other statement, it is indented relative to the `case`. As for the `case` relative to `switch`  - well I don't know.

But I'm completely with you - and formatting is a matter of personal preference anyway. Since the formatting rules in Xcode are not explicitly defined - it cannot be a bug ;)

FWIW, I prefere this style

```
switch x {
    case 1:
        // do something
        break
    case 2:
        // do something else
        break
    default:
        // default
        break
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I also prefer this style but Xcode has a big problem - it is years behind in functionality compared to other IDEs.

Comment: By the way, in Swift, you don't need any `break` in a `switch`. It's implicit. You have the `fallthrough` statement if you want to force a fall through cases

Comment: @BPCorp You are correct. But a case clause should also have at least _one_ statement in Swift.